# Textmate not working after adding /sw/lib

Tags: textmate

I am trying to use textmate from commandline as: mate file.txt but it doesn't work anymore after adding /sw/lib to my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is annoying
because I want to be able add "/sw/lib" to my path as I have some programs there I want to use. How can I fix this issue:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_TIFFClientOpen
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /sw/lib/libTIFF.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I just removed /sw/lib from the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and it now works.
In my case /sw/lib was added to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in the .bashrc file which is read each time I start a terminal session.
Now I don't know whether there will be side effects on other fink softwares...
I'll let you know if I find anything.